# Redirecht 301 .htaccess puzzle

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm working on a website *www.successfulspeakernow.com* that has been moved from the regular root **public_html** folder to the folder **public_html/successfulspeakernow.com**

In the new site there are a number of new pages and some old ones have been cancelled. 
Now in the root folder **public_html** there is this **.htaccess** file which contains this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^successfulspeakernow\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.successfulspeakernow\.com$
RewriteRule ^tedx\-amsterdam\-women$ "http\:\/\/www\.successfulspeakernow\.com\/category\/blog" [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^successfulspeakernow.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.successfulspeakernow.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !successfulspeakernow.com/
RewriteRule (.*) /successfulspeakernow.com/$1 [L]
Redirect 301 http://www.successfulspeakernow.com/introducing-speaker-in-the-spotlight http://www.successfulspeakernow.com/category/blog

#SetEnv PHPRC /etc/php_succesfulspeaker.ini

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

then in the folder **public_html/successfulspeakernow.com** there is a second **.htaccess** file that contains this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /introducing-speaker-in-the-spotlight http://www.successfulspeakernow.com/category/blog
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


</IfModule>

# BEGIN MemberPress Rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} mplk=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
RewriteCond /home/succes96/public_html/successfulspeakernow.com/wp-content/uploads/mepr/rules/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wp-admin|wp-includes)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(txt|php|phtml|jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|svg|woff|ttf|xml|TXT|PHP|PHTML|JPG|JPEG|GIF|CSS|PNG|JS|ICO|SVG|WOFF|TTF|XML)
RewriteRule . /~succes96/successfulspeakernow.com/wp-content/plugins/memberpress/lock.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END MemberPress Rules

# END WordPress
```

As you can see I have included a Redirect 301 line. It doesn't seem to work. When I type in: *www.successfulspeakernow.com/introducing-speaker-in-the-spotlight* in my browser, I am NOT redirected to the blog page, but I get a 404. My hosting provider (Siteground.com) couldn't find what was wrong with this and suggested to redirect this (and all other) URLs through the cPanel redirect function.

Can anyone tell me, if I am doing something wrong? This should work, shouldn't it? forgot a line of code? ehr....?

Thanx,

Thom
Thomsterdam

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mod_rewrite instead of mod_alias. The `Redirect` directive is part of mod_alias and both modules will process a URL, which means all your rules get jumbled up and end up messing with the same URL.

Remove the `Redirect` line and replace it with:

```
RewriteRule /introducing-speaker-in-the-spotlight http://www.successfulspeakernow.com/category/blog [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

This response is only to clarify why your config is not working. **Jon Lin** solution should work.

The code is not working because mod_rewrite takes precedence:

This is changing your requested URI:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^successfulspeakernow.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.successfulspeakernow.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !successfulspeakernow.com/
RewriteRule (.*) /successfulspeakernow.com/$1 [L]
```

Your request of `www.successfulspeakernow.com/introducing-speaker-in-the-spotlight` transforms internally (an prior to mod_alias working) to this `www.successfulspeakernow.com/successfulspeakernow.com//introducing-speaker-in-the-spotlight`

Then, the redirect does not apply, since the URL is not matching..